# Book from the 1990s about people from Earth being sent into space to save them

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book in the 90s. Something to do with the Earth almost being ruined and they sent people into space to save them.  They were put in a sleep and there was a girl who woke early for some reason, I think a bad guy was involved.  She was meant for a boy named David who was supposed to save the human race somehow. I think he lost his memory?

His story was he wakes years later and people can’t remember his name. They call him Dahben and there’s some prophecy about him saving them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to remember the cover art at all, or any other character names?

Comment: Wish I could. No, I don’t remember it at all.